# rabbitmq message data corruption

Tags: rabbitmq, pika

I try to use rabbitmq to dispatch a small bzipped message less than 10k to other machines.
It usually works fine and fast.
Though, sometimes I get a data corrupt error when my client tries to decompress the message.
I search for the cause on google, but since rabbitmq atop of tcp, there is very little chance the data is corrupted in the network layer.

Since I use the ack mechanism, the corrupt message goes back to another client, and the message will not be corrupted the second time, can anyone tell what the problem is?

rabbitmq version: 3.3.1
rabbitmq client: pika 0.9.13
os: centos 6.5 x86

Comment: Do you send 10k with a single publish?

Comment: Yes, i declare message structure as the layout:*metadata(32bits),datalen(32bits),data(bytes)*, all in network byte order.So i can make sure the data is fully recieved by comparing the datalen and the actual data size.When publishing, i sent the bytes in that layout, while receiving message i check the data size. And, sometimes, the check process is passed but the decompress process fails, it sounds like the message is modified after received by the client. @Gas, by the way, i have confirmed the  publish action which pika and rabbitmq supports.